# Add camera moving along curve in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script that creates a closed curve, and I now want to have a camera which moves along the curve and looks slightly ahead on the curve. The camera moves, but it doesn't stay on the curve itself. (I also haven't tried to tackle the looking ahead).

```
import bpy

points = [((-10.875,-0.444,0.122),(-16.375,5.056,0.122),(-5.375,-5.944,0.122)),
          ((11.125,-0.444,0.122),(4.420,-9.648,0.122),(17.602,8.447,0.122)),
          ((22.125,10.556,0.122),(9.216,6.553,8.612),(31.022,13.315,-5.729)),
          ((-0.284,16.306,0.122),(-25.732,16.306,-49.859),(25.164,16.306,50.103))]

curveData = bpy.data.curves.new('path', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2

polyline = curveData.splines.new('BEZIER')
polyline.bezier_points.add(len(points)-1)
polyline.use_cyclic_u = True
for i, ((x,y,z), (lh_x, lh_y, lh_z), (rh_x, rh_y, rh_z)) in enumerate(points):
    polyline.bezier_points[i].co = (x, y, z)
    polyline.bezier_points[i].handle_left = (lh_x, lh_y, lh_z,)
    polyline.bezier_points[i].handle_right = (rh_x, rh_y, rh_z)

curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('path', curveData)

scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
curveOB.select = True

cam = bpy.data.cameras.new("Cam")
cam_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Cam", cam)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(cam_ob)

cam_ob.location = points[0][0]

cam_ob.select = True
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW')
```

Answer (score 1):

The camera is following the curve, it is just offset right now so the behaviour looks odd.

You need to set your camera to the starting point of the curve. Which is the point (-0.284,16.306,0.122).